# if $S=\sin x+2\sin (2x)+\cdots+n\sin nx$,$C=\cos x +2\cos (2x)+\cdots+n\cos (nx)$

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, summation, proof-writing, telescopic-series

if:

$S=\sin x+2\sin (2x)+\cdots+n\sin nx$,

$C=\cos x +2\cos (2x)+\cdots+n\cos (nx).$

prove that $4\sin^2 (x/2).S=(n+1)\sin (nx)-n\sin(nx+x)$

I can solve this easily using complex numbers(ie taking $C+iS$,which becomes an [AGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence)) but  was  wondering if it can be solved using basic trig identities.

**Source** S.L.Loney plane trigonometry

Thank you!

Comment: I believe that this can be done with induction

Comment: @Dr.Mathva thank you for giving idea i will try!

Comment: If when you've given it a try you still get stuck, edit in your efforts so we can help with a specific step. However, hopefully you should be OK, because it's just telescoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to see that for $\sin\frac{x}{2}=0$ it's true.

But for $\sin\frac{x}{2}\neq0$ by the telescopic summation we obtain: $$S=-\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\cos{kx}\right)'=-\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos{kx}}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right)'=$$
$$=-\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(\sin\left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)x-\sin\left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right)x\right)}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right)'=-\left(\frac{\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)x-\sin\frac{x}{2}}{2\sin\frac{x}{2}}\right)'=$$
$$=-\frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)x\sin\frac{x}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)x\cos\frac{x}{2}}{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin(n+1)x+\sin{nx}\right)-\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)(\sin(n+1)x-\sin{nx})}{4\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{(n+1)\sin{nx}-n\sin(n+1)x}{4\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}.$$

Comment: Ingenious method using derivatives ,Thank you for your time !

Comment: @Albus Dumbledore You are welcome!